# Do while with a boolean as the condition in c++?

Tags: c++, boolean, do-while

so i want to know how a boolean acts in a condition statement in the following code

```
bool flag = true;

do { 
    d += data[i]; 
    if (d > 15 || i == 3) { 
          flag = false; 
    } 
    i = i + 1; 
} while (flag);
```

when will it exit the dowhile loop?

Comment: It will exit the loop when it reaches the bottom, and the flag is false (not at the exact moment when flag is set to false).

Comment: ok so it only exits when its false?

Comment: Yes, because if it is true, it runs the loop for at least one more iteration.

Comment: remind you that the C++ is a procedural code.

Comment: You can replace `do` with `beginning_of_loop:` and `while(flag)` with `if(flag) goto beginning_of_loop;`.

Answer (score 3):

If either `d > 15` or `i == 3` evaluates to true, *`i` will get incremented* and the loop will stop.

In other words, `flag` is only checked at the end of each iteration, even though it might be set to `false` in the middle of one.

Comment: @ACizzle: If `flag` is false initially, and stays false, the loop will exit after the first iteration.

Comment: so if a boolean is in a condition it exits when its false...is that always the case?

Comment: @ACizzle: No offence, but my recommendation at this point is to pick up a basic C++ tutorial. It will explain how a `do`-`while` loop works, and will be a much more efficient way to learn the basics.

Comment: man i get the do while and everything...it was just a simple example of code...i dont know how booleans  act...

Answer (score 1):

It will exit when `(d > 15 || i == 3)` which means `(d > 15 or i == 3)`.

`i` is incremented at each iteration therefore if `i` is < 3 at the beginning of the program we are sure that at a certain point it will reach `i == 3` and break the loop.

On `d` we can't tell much since we don't know it initial value nor its behavior inside the loop since we don't know anything about `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your values of `d` and `i`...
As soon as `d` is greater than 15 or `i` is equal to 3, `flag` becomes `false` and the loop will end.

This might not happen in the same iteration, though. For example if `i` is incremented to 3 in a loop, it will be evaluated in the following loop first and `flag` might be set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

It will break the while when SUM of first 3 values in array Data[] be greater than "15", or break if does not be greater than 15 the SUM of first 3 values.

[It's depend on initial value of "i"]